# Prove or disprove: $|\det(Q)|=1 \Longrightarrow Q$ is unitary.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I wonder whether the statement of above can be written as an equivalence. So far I could prove the other direction $(\Longleftarrow)$:

If $Q$ is unitary, then

$1=\det(I)=\det(Q^HQ)=\det(Q^H)\det(Q)=\det(Q)\det(Q)=\det(Q)^2 \Longleftrightarrow 1=|\det(Q)|$

However, I can't prove or disprove the other direction mentioned in the question title.

Comment: What are simple $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant $1$? Look at some examples.

Comment: Let $Q=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions! I got it. Will you write it as an answer Adam, so you get the credits and I close the question?

Comment: All eigenvalues are equal to one does not help either $\left[\matrix{1 & 1\\0 & 1}\right]$.

Comment: @ndrizza there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$Q=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$